# Interaction between JDBC connection pool and Apache Phoenix JDBC driver: is thread Pool per connection or per driver?

Tags: jdbc, apache-phoenix

I wonder if anyone has experience using Apache Phoenix JDBC driver with a JDBC connection pools (our environment is Tomcat, but that shouldn't matter much).

Since phoenix JDBC driver implements both SQL parser and execution engine inside the driver itself, it uses its own worker thread pool and a task queue to process queries.

It's not clear from the documentation whether this worker thread pool is created once per driver, or it's being created for each thread that loads the driver.

In other words, if I have 10 open connection in a JDBC pool using phoenix driver, will the number of threads spawn by JVM be 10*phoenix.query.threadPoolSize or it still will be phoenix.query.threadPoolSize (as all the connections will share global worker pool and the task queue)?

Comment: This is probably a question that you should ask on the [User or Developer mailinglist of Apache Phoenix](http://phoenix.apache.org/mailing_list.html)